# JList append row at top instead at bottom

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I was searching on web regarding this but could not find any relevant answer. Actually, my `JList` currently appends new row at the bottom of list. What my problem case needs is I want to add or prepend new row added to my `JList` model (at the top). How can I achieve this?

Comment: assuming you are using DefaultListModel: read the api doc very near the method "add" which you are already using ... assuming you are using a custom implementation: implement what you need

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had you visited the java docs, you would have known of a certain method `add(int index, Object element)`  for the `listModel` which in case should be used to insert the element at the **index** you desire.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
DefaultListModel myListModel = (DefaultListModel) myList.getModel();
myListModel.add(0, "new row added at top");
```

Comment: Hi adel, thanks very much for your quick reply... It worked... I actually did not use it because i thought it will replace my top most row.... :D

Comment: @Adel Boutros no idea what did you talk about (@deprecated), maybe Java7 something about that, I deleted my answer as duplicate answer

Comment: @kartikmittal - if you interpret _Inserts the specified element at the specified position_ as possibly mean "replace", then maybe you should take a course in English ;-) But even without - if you have seen the method, simply _try it out_ - it's a matter of seconds (much quicker than posting here and checking for an answer) and nothing much can happen

Comment: @mKorbel if you got to this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#setElementAt%28java.lang.Object,%20int%29) you will see a small note saying what I said. It's not deprecated, it is just not recommended

Comment: @Adel Boutros (-: we live in another century and millenium too, Java5 /6 changed lots of thigs :-) +1 for faster answer

Comment: @mKorbel I referenced the 1.4 to tell you since when the Note is present. In fact, if you replace the 1.4.2 in the link with 6 (Java 6), you still get the same note. It's not funny to make fun of others. you should at least have checked

Comment: you are right, I'm sorry, I looked at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#setValueAt%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29, as an answer to another Forum, and suprised what did you talking about,